# Laravel+FatalErrorException in Collection.php line 11: Interface 'Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\QueueableCollection' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this code

```
use App\User;

use Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Libraries\CustomLib;

class UsersController extends Controller
{

   public function postLogin(){
        // var_dump($_POST);
        $email = \Input::get('username');
        $password = \Input::get('password');

        $user = User::where("email",$email)->first();
        var_dump($user_info);
  }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
FatalErrorException in Collection.php line 11: Interface 'Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\QueueableCollection' not found
```

Not sure what that means.

Any ideas please how to solve this.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this happen only for the **User** model and which version is your laravel/framework inside your composer.lock file?

Comment: @TheFallen version is `"version": "v5.2.36"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this one by downloading QueueableCollection.php in this link:
https://github.com/illuminate/contracts/tree/master/Queue

Looks like that file wasn't pulled when doing composer update. Not sure though.

Thanks SO! :)

Comment: Having same issue after composer update in laravel 5.2. Thanks to this answer that save my time. Cheers !!!

Answer (score 0):

I update my composer to use older version of illuminate/database and it is working now. I guess the problem is with the new version of eloquent.
`"illuminate/database": "5.2.*"` to `"illuminate/database": "5.2.21"`

Answer (score -1):

The particular error means that a record collection retrieved from the Database as a Laravel Collection does not implement the particular methods outlined in the QueueableCollection Interface. This is often due to a missing dependency. Typically, Laravels models allow for serialisation. In this case, it's because the User model can be used to send out emails for password reminders etc... When this interface is missing, Laravel throws an Exception stating that a required component cannot be instantiated. This method is also known as "coding to an interface".

Further Info:

It looks like you are attempting a manual authentication. Please ensure that your App\User model implements Authenticatable:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticable as AuthenticableTrait;

class User extends Model implements Authenticable {
    use AuthenticableTrait;
}
```

This is covered in the Documentation

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authenticating-users

To save you a trip to the site, here's a paraphrasing of their example using your example:

```
use App\User;

use Auth;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Libraries\CustomLib;

class UsersController extends Controller
{

    public function postLogin()
    {
        $email = \Input::get('username');
        $password = \Input::get('password');

        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
            // Authentication passed. Redirect to "dashboard"
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }
    }

}
```

Details of the user can now be accessed via the Auth Facade:

```
Auth::user()->name;
Auth::user()->email;
Auth::user()->id;
```

`Auth::user()` is tied to the session. If enabled, a remember token is also set as a cookie allowing for logins to persist beyond the session expiration time limit (I believe the default is 2 hours).

More information:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-authattemp-method?page=1

`**Edit:**` Namespacing for Model brought in, corrected inheritance

Comment: How is the **AuthenticableTrait** going to fix an error from **QueueableCollection** which is a contact for **Eloquent**?

Comment: I had a similar issue, it was fixed by reading the documentation and having a look further in depth: https://github.com/laravel/framework/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=getQueueableIds%28%29  If it can't retrieve the ID's for a model collection, it throws this error. Non-default App\User models can sometimes cause errors related to Authentication, Authorization, Queueing, Serialisation, De-Serialisation and more.

Comment: Ok, but the error is for a missing interface and **Authenticable** trait is used in the Illuminate's User class by default which extends **Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model**, not **\Eloquent**.